# how can i run force.com project in eclipse?

Tags: force.com

Actually We have developed a application on salesforce enviornment using apex programming,  and setup the eclipse ide with username and password of force.com which uploaded whole classes of apex and pages into eclipse. now how can i run this force.com project into eclipse locally onto my windows machine.

Scenario -->

We have created custom object (Users__c) in salesforce. Now our application creating users using this custom object.

Now i want to see the logs that has been generated by these users. In Salesforce we can only monitor logs for standard users.

Comment: logs are generated for all usres

Comment: Running/executing code at this time is always done server side. It's rather unclear which logs of your custom object you expect to see.  Logs are based on the session you're authenticated with (as standard user). Maybe you could edit your question to give some more details and a more specific question.

Comment: It should probably be pointed out that if you're using your custom user object and custom authentication to allow people to use the system who do not have licenses then you're more than likely breaking the rules of your license agreement with Salesforce.

Answer (score 3):

Eclipse as an IDE for Force.com development is a bit of a misnomer. You can use the IDE to write, upload and run tests but you cannot use it to run code locally. There is no way to run force.com / salesforce applications on a local machine. You can only run the code on the salesforce cloud, either in a developer sandbox, or a developer org. -- Wherever you uploaded the code. You'll need to login to your developer sandbox / dev org using either http://test.salesforce.com OR http://login.salesforce.com (respectively).